# If it is possible to install crome app as chrome extension's dependency?

Tags: google-chrome, sockets, google-chrome-extension, tcp, google-chrome-app

I need run tcp server for my chrome extension.
There is exist [sockets API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer) but it is available only for chrome application, and I know that is possible to comunicate between chrome application and chrome extension.
What I want to do is create chrome application that will serve tcp server for chrome extension. 
Is exist a better way to serve tcp server for chrome extension?
Is it possible to install chrome app programmatically as a dependency of chrome extension?

Comment: Chrome apps are deprecated except in ChromeOS. Maybe you can use WebSocket instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm I can use WebSocket. But as far as I know  it's impossible to run WebSocket in chrome extension.

Comment: No, but you can have the extension create a notification of some sort to inform the user of the dependency and also detect whether the app is present.